# React route not rendering (additionally getting a 404 for main.js)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using React Router like so in the development server mode:

```
 <Router history={history}>
     <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path="/install" component={InstallationPage} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/browse/:externalId" component={ViewIssuePage} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
        <Route component={NoMatch} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>

function PrivateRoute ({component: Component, ...rest }) {
    const isUserStored = localStorage.getItem('user');

    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
                (isUserStored) ? <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )} />
    )
}
```

However, when I point my browser to `localhost:8080/browse/test`, React doesn't render. Checking the browser inspector, I see an error 404 on `/browse/main.js`, which is obviously correct.

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Can you add your PrivateRoute component please ?

Comment: @GaddMaster I've added it.

Comment: That "<Component" looks dodgy, not sure. Can you make a online program where we can mess round together ? You could just delete "component={ViewIssuePage}" and manually include it in the PrivateRoute using a switch staement and a label, just to test. Let me check, ill be back in a bit, maybe a while, you should try that yourself in meantime

Comment: @GaddMaster I swapped the PrivateRoute out for a Route and is still is erroring. I don't think it's the PrivateRoute though?

Comment: I actually need add this same kinda AuthRoute now this weekend. We had one before, worked fine, cant rememeber of top of head how it looked. Either way we solve this now today

Comment: can we look at the program online together somehow ?

Comment: @GaddMaster I'm trying to upload the source code to GitHub

Comment: Make a JSFiddle program and share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-butterfly-2c93b?file=/src/App.js:0-1283) based upon your code.  Everything appears to function.  Compare your solution to that.

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

function Test() {
  return (
    <div>
      Test 1 <Link href="/">Private Link</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

function Login() {
  return <div>Login</div>;
}

function Private() {
  return <div>Private</div>;
}

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  // Try tweaking this value from false to true
  const isUserStored = localStorage.getItem("user");

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isUserStored ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/install" component={Test} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/browse/:externalId" component={Private} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={Private} />
          <Route component={Test} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```